# Dynamic assets prefix in Ember-CLI build-generated index.html

Tags: ember-cli

I asked this question earlier today, and then deleted it, cause I thought I found an answer that was too obvious to post on here. Basically, how do you change something like this in **dist/index.html**:

```
<script src="assets/my.js"></script>
```

to something like this:

```
<script src="http://my.assets.com/assets/my.js"></script>
```

I instantly realized that I can just set the **src** in **app/index.html** and it will appear in **dist/index.html**.

But now I'm realizing that there's a better, if slightly more complex, solution - one that allows different settings in different environments. So I am re-adding the question and posting the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution requires [ember-cli-inline-content](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-inline-content)

**Brocfile.js:**

```
global require, module, process;
```

...

```
if (process.env.EMBER_ENV === 'development') {
  app.options.inlineContent = {
    assetPrefix: {
      content:  'http://my.assets.com/'
    }
  };
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<script src="{{content-for 'assetPrefix'}}assets/my.js"></script>
```